# Shared hosting account connection reset

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, shared-hosting

The server will serve up static files fine, but anything with aspx will return the below message in Firefox:

```
The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading
```

Firebug `NET` tab shows `aborted`

IE10 shows

```
This page can't be displayed
```

Chrome shows

```
This webpage is not available
```

ASP.NET Webforms 4.5, uploaded through Visual Studio 2012, using  ftp publish in release

Comment: Oh wow they finally enabled ASP.NET 4.5?

Comment: yea, I'm on the ultimate security whatever plan though, not sure if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be the Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls

After going into nuget and uninstalling the package, as well as commenting out all the places where its referenced, the error went away.

This means that the automatic switching to mobile is gone, but at least my site is up and  running now.

What's frustrating is that godaddy help desk and their advanced hosting support claim that they did not run any updates or patches, but four days ago the site was working fine. Of course, I have not made any publishes on my end.

Answer (score 0):

Just comment out the feature in App_Start/RouteConfig.cs and re-deploy through FTP publishing.

```
public static class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        //routes.EnableFriendlyUrls();
    }
}
```